# Python program don't run

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I am doing one program to plot a scatter 3d. I am using the code of this page:
http://pythonprogramming.net/matplotlib-3d-scatterplot-tutorial/

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y =[5,6,2,3,13,4,1,2,4,8]
z =[2,3,3,3,5,7,9,11,9,10]
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
plt.show()
```

But for (x, y, z) I get the data from csv, using import csv, reader, etc.
The code runs perfectly on shell console, and draw the scatter.
The problem is: when I save de file.py, and execute, it don´t run , but if I place the file in the folder of Python34 (the instalation folder of my python), runs perfectly.

And if I dont use csv to import the data, I mean, use:

```
x =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y =[5,6,2,3,13,4,1,2,4,8]
z =[2,3,3,3,5,7,9,11,9,10]
```

the numbers in the code, the file.py works perfect inside python34 folder or other folders...
Anyone knows how can i solve to execute the file in others folders of my computer.
Thanks

Comment: Could you possibly improve the title at all and be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to open a relative path like

```
"data.csv"
```

Instead of the full path

```
"C:\\folder\\stuff\\data.csv"
```

So when you are in the same working directory, you can read the file fine. But if the script is running out of a different working directory, it won't be able to find your csv file just using the relative pathname.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the problem